# Forcing a save as dialogue from any web browser from JSF application

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a modal that will be shown and then I have an export button which should bring up the save dialog, if I have use h:commandButton, the validation checks are bypassed , but works well. If I use a4j:commandButton, validations are done perfectly but I dont see the save file dialog.

Can somebody help me.

thanks

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far? It's easier to find an error if you actually  post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do RichFaces, so I can't tell from top of head, but [Google](http://google.com/search?q=a4j+file+download) learns me that `a4j:htmlCommandLink` may help. If it does and you'd rather like to have a button, then just throw some CSS in to make the link look like a button.